# pandas dataframe slice rows based on date indexes

Tags: python, date, pandas, slice

I have read the historic market data in csv file, as follows

```
df = pandas.read_csv('http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPl', 
            index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df.head()   


              Open       High        Low      Close     Volume    Adj Close
Date                                                                       
2016-02-12  94.190002  94.500000  93.010002  93.989998  40121700  93.989998
2016-02-11  93.790001  94.720001  92.589996  93.699997  49686200  93.699997
2016-02-10  95.919998  96.349998  94.099998  94.269997  42245000  94.269997
2016-02-09  94.290001  95.940002  93.930000  94.989998  44331200  94.989998
2016-02-08  93.129997  95.699997  93.040001  95.010002  54021400  95.010002
```

So, I am using the given dates as the row indexes, and I want to slice this data frame, so for example select all the rows between 2008-01-01 to 2015-12-31

I tried this command

```
df.loc['20080101':'200151231']
```

but it doesn't return anything as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your index is reverse sorted.  You can either sort it again via `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` or else do the following to reverse the index and then use index selection:

```
>>> df[::-1].ix['2016-02-09':'2016-02-11']
                 Open       High        Low      Close    Volume  Adj_Close
Date                                                                       
2016-02-09  94.290001  95.940002  93.930000  94.989998  44331200  94.989998
2016-02-10  95.919998  96.349998  94.099998  94.269997  42245000  94.269997
2016-02-11  93.790001  94.720001  92.589996  93.699997  49686200  93.699997
```